# Getting the names of a field based on the same foreign key but different values in one statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

My brain is melting a bit with this one, please go easy I am a rookie.

I have a flights table with a flight origin(airport id from airports table) and a flight destination(also an airport id from airports table). Both fields are foreign keys of the airport id. I can get the results I need with two different selects but can I get the results using only one SELECT or do I need to rethink how I designed the database?

```
SELECT airports.airportName AS 'FROM'
FROM airports
INNER JOIN flights ON airports.id = flights.flightOrigin
WHERE flights.id = 1;

SELECT airports.airportName AS 'TO'
FROM airports
INNER JOIN flights ON airports.id = flights.flightDestination
WHERE flights.id = 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the `airports` table twice and give a different alias to each instance (like `a` and `b`):

```
SELECT a.airportName AS 'FROM', b.airportName AS 'TO'
FROM flights f
INNER JOIN airports a ON a.id = f.flightOrigin
INNER JOIN airports b ON b.id = f.flightDestination
WHERE f.id = 1;
```